# Docker magento 2 setup issues with Mysql (markshust/docker-magento)

Tags: magento2, php, database, docker

Facing a MySQL connection issue while Magento2 setup with docker at local

I have followed the steps mentioned in the existing project in the below link

markshust/docker-magento: Mark Shust's Docker Configuration for Magento (github.com)

[markshust/docker-magento](https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/#existing-projects)

I am not able to dump my SQL backup and when I connect bin/mysql, it connected perfectly fine but SQL queries are not working. it's not display anything even after multiple hits on the entering button.

Mysql connection not established I guess, so please help me to resolve this error and also find the attached screens for reference.

Note: I am able to setup default Magento perfectly and no issues are faced.

Tech stack :
MacBook pro with M1 chip, 16 GB memory

Please find the attached screenshots for reference

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed this message!

You can take a MySQL dump by running:

`bin/mysqldump > ~/Sites/yoursite/magento.sql`

Regarding `bin/mysql`, that should work out of the box. Perhaps there was a bug when you tested it. I just ran it and it executed the SQL immediately:

[image]

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Hi the issue is in your sql host please check the sql db host name.

to check sql host run  `docker ps` in windows PowerShell

[image]

then replace host name.